# Magento: machine memory allocation

Tags: php, magento, memory-management

Currently I have a Magento shopping cart running on iweb share web hosting.

Recently, customers complain that the page is sometime blank, and I found that it is because 500 error with not enough memory.

I told the admin guy, he provided me a script which use php `memory_get_peak_usage`

He said the application require 32mb to run, and said if 30 concurrent people visit the page, that mean 32mb X 30 which is almost 1000mb for memory cost.

I am not sure if he tells the truth or not, because for Magento, even turn on the cache of Magento, it requires 3mb.

So I am wondering if `memory_get_peak_usage` X concurrent users is equal to the total memory usage?

Comment: Try increasing you php_memory_limit to 32mb. Also phpinfo and check how much is allot at the moment. It has be 32 mb min. I came across a problem where we had to increase it to 256mb because we were facing problems in uploading the images/downloadable products.

Comment: this is not related to php_memory_limit, it is related to the resource of the server

Answer (score 2):

Your admin guy is over simplifying things a bit, but what he's saying essentially rings true.  Magento is a RAM hog. The [leading Magento hosts](https://affiliates.nexcess.net/idevaffiliate.php?id=1626) (affiliate link, click it and buy something and I get a kickback) give their entry level Magento plans 16GB of memory.  That's 16,384 GB.

The "iweb share web hosting" is not a suitable server host for Magento.  Move your store.

Comment: 16 GB...so crazy, i should not chose magento at the begining, but its programming structure is good

Comment: 16GB can be had for under $200.  The commodification makes for weird trade-offs.

Comment: i have make a stress test on my other server with same magneto code, although it output 42mb for the useage of ram, however no matter how many user, the usage is 42mb, instead of 42mb x no of user, the ram usage is depend on content instead of user profile

Comment: you can run with 16GB with no problem. Amazon aws is a good option, otherwise https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/ offer a good pricing for cloud hosting with one-click-apps including magento https://www.digitalocean.com/features/one-click-apps/

Comment: @user192344 check this post for amazon aws http://www.aschroder.com/2013/04/magento-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk-the-scalability-silver-bullet/